# Why is my cursor not working properly?

Tags: plsql, cursor, procedure

I set up a cursor to fetch multiple lines in my procedure result. However, it seems that it does not work by generating this error message:
"01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested"

The other parts of the codes do not have problems as I tried when there is only one record, it runs fine. But when there is multiple records, my cursor does not seem to work. Why is that?

```
set serveroutput on

declare
   get_term scores.term%type;
   get_sectno scores.sectno%type;
   get_sid scores.sid%type;
   get_score scores.points%type;
   status boolean;

   procedure total_score (aterm in out scores.term%type,
                 asectno in out scores.sectno%type,
                 asid out scores.sid%type,
                 ascore out scores.points%type,
           status out boolean)
   is
   cursor find is 
      select scores.term, scores.sectno, sid, sum(points/maxpoints*weight)
      from scores, components
      where scores.term=components.term
      and scores.sectno=components.sectno
      group by scores.term, scores.sectno, sid;
   find_rec find%rowtype;   
   begin
      open find;
      fetch find into find_rec;
      while find%found loop
         select scores.term, scores.sectno, sid, sum(points/maxpoints*weight)
         into aterm, asectno, asid, ascore
         from scores, components
         where scores.term=components.term
         and scores.term=aterm
         and scores.sectno=components.sectno
         and scores.sectno=asectno
         and scores.compname=components.compname
         group by scores.term, scores.sectno, sid;
         status:=true;
         fetch find into find_rec;
      end loop;
      close find;
   exception
      when no_data_found then
         status:=false;
   end;
begin
   get_term:='F12';
   get_sectno:='1031';
   total_score (get_term, get_sectno, get_sid, get_score, status);
   if (status) then
      dbms_output.put_line(get_term||' '||get_sectno||' '||get_sid||' '||get_score);
   else
      dbms_output.put_line('Record not found.');
   end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite like as follows:

```
open find;
loop
 fetch find into find_rec;
 Exit when find%NOTFOUND;
...
end loop;
close find;
```

But, why you open this cursor if you don't use its values in the inner Select?
However, I think the error is generated because the select inside the cursor returns two or more rows in one or more iterations.
For more informations, see, for example, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html. Bye, Igor

Update:

```
CREATE TABLE SCORES(SID INTEGER, TERM VARCHAR2(10), SECTNO VARCHAR2(10), COMPNAME VARCHAR2(50));
CREATE TABLE COMPONENTS(TERM VARCHAR2(10), SECTNO VARCHAR2(10), COMPNAME VARCHAR2(50), POINTS INTEGER, MAXPOINTS INTEGER, WEIGHT INTEGER);



INSERT ALL
INTO SCORES VALUES(1,'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
INTO SCORES VALUES(5,'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
INTO SCORES VALUES(2,'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF')
INTO SCORES VALUES(3,'GGG', 'HHH', 'III')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;


INSERT ALL
INTO COMPONENTS VALUES('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 1, 2, 3)
INTO COMPONENTS VALUES('DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 4, 5, 6)
INTO COMPONENTS VALUES('GGG', 'HHH', 'III', 7, 8, 9)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;

COMMIT;



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TOTAL_SCORE (ATERM in OUT SCORES.TERM%type,
                 ASECTNO in OUT SCORES.SECTNO%type) AS
 cursor find (cpAterm VARCHAR2, cpAsectno VARCHAR2) is 
      select scores.term, scores.sectno, sid, sum(points/maxpoints*weight) AS SUM_SCORE
         from scores RIGHT JOIN components ON
         scores.term=components.term
         and scores.sectno=components.sectno
         and scores.compname=components.compname
         WHERE
          scores.term=cpAterm
          AND scores.sectno=cpAsectno
         group by scores.term, scores.sectno, sid;
   find_rec find%rowtype; 

   counter INTEGER:=0;

BEGIN
 open find(ATERM, ASECTNO);
 LOOP
       fetch find into find_rec;
      exit when find%notfound;
      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(find_rec.TERM||' '||find_rec.sectno||' '||find_rec.SID||' '||find_rec.SUM_SCORE);
      if (find_rec.term IS NOT NULL) then
      dbms_output.put_line(find_rec.TERM||' '||find_rec.sectno||' '||find_rec.SID||' '||find_rec.SUM_SCORE);
      counter:=counter+1;
      END IF;
      end loop;
      close find;
      if counter = 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('NO DATA FOUND FOR: ' || ATERM || ', ' || ASECTNO);
      end if;

END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
 get_term VARCHAR2(10);
 get_sectno VARCHAR2(10);
begin
   get_term:='AAA';
   get_sectno:='BBB';
   total_score (get_term, get_sectno);
  END;
/

DROP TABLE SCORES;
DROP TABLE COMPONENTS;
```

Comment: I tried to use your method to rewrite the code but it does not work either. What do you mean by " the select inside the cursor returns two or more rows in one or more iterations"? Isn't that the cursor is used to deal with multiple rows?

Comment: At each iteration  of the cursor, the select must return exactly one row to allow the setting of variables: a variable --》a value. So, in an iteration, if the select return, for example, two records, what values you insert in the aterm, asectno, asid, ascore variables? The values of the first row? The values of the second row?

Comment: I understand that. But how would that happen in my codes? Are you saying that my cursor is not defined correctly or I do not use it correctly? How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Execute the select: I think it'll retrieve two or more records; if so, for example,   filter with cursor values to retrieve exactly one row each iteration; for example: WHERE scores.term=find_rec.something... and finally I suggest to use the join in the from clause (from a inner join b on a.id=b.id etc).

Comment: Wait, I am confused. I thought I am using the cursor for multiple records accessing. Yes, the select statement will return more than one row of records. But isn't that the cursor will move from one row of record to another to process them all? Isn't that is the purpose of the loop?

Comment: Yes, the cursor retrieves all the records of the query one at time but, in the loop, you execute at every iteration, another query that fetches n record and tries to assign them at the variables you declared. You are executing the query of the cursor and n times the query inside the loop: these are two distinct things.

Comment: If you are interested about the values retrieve by the cursor query,  you have to access them in the loop through the find_rec.term, find_rec.sectno, etc; and in the cursor declaration,  for your convenience,  give an alias to the sum and access it by find_rec.your_sum_alias.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a little bit confused regarding the query was executed n times in the loop. Can you show me how I can revise the code to make it right?

Comment: Ok smart_cookie, I have update my answer with a working example. Bye, Igor

Comment: I think I got what you meant now. So I should not have both cursor and the procedure using doing the same SELECT. I revised mine and now it worked well to pick up multiple values. However, it could not pick up the no_data_found exception, I am wondering it is because I am using the cursor. And is that why you are using the counter to help you see whether there is a "no_data_found" situation? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I used the counter to trace the no data found and not make things more complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and insight! I appreciate it!

Comment: The last things: in my example, I think you can remove the if (find_rec.term IS NOT NULL) then ... try it yourself! Bye, Igor

Comment: Yep, in my code I did not include that one. Cause I think cursor handles the no_data_found error automatically.